# Sequelize: Avoid duplicates when create with manyToMany associations

Tags: sql, post, orm, sequelize.js

I'm developing a small e-commerce to sell cinema tickets. I'm using Sequelize to design all models and their associations. The issue I'm facing is related with the route defined to create the final order:

```
Order.create({
        userId: req.body.userId,                   // Number
        sessionId: req.body.sessionId,             // Number
        seats: req.body.seats,                     // Array of objects
        offsiteProducts: req.body.offsiteProducts  // Array of objects
    },
    {
    include: [
        {
            model: Seat,
            attributes: ['area', 'number', 'roomId']
        },
        {
            model: OffsiteProduct,
            attributes: ['name', 'unitPrice']
        }
    ]
}).then(order => {
    res.json(order);
})
```

The relation between models is as follows:

```
User.hasMany(Order);
Order.belongsTo(User);

Session.hasMany(Order);
Order.belongsTo(Session);

Seat.belongsToMany(Order, { through: "reserved_seats" });
Order.belongsToMany(Seat, { through: "reserved_seats" });

OffsiteProduct.belongsToMany(Order, { through: ReservedOffsiteProduct });
Order.belongsToMany(OffsiteProduct, { through: ReservedOffsiteProduct });
```

For the "one-to-many" relationships, passing a foreign key is enough for Sequelize to associate models properly.

But for **"many-to-many" associations** ("belongsToMany" in Sequelize) it would **duplicate** the data entered for seats and offsite products and create it both as part of the order and as a new independent seat and offsite product respectively.

How can I avoid this behaviour and include the arrays of seats and offsite products only inside the final order? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to execute everything in a transaction.  That way, it will be atomic, i.e. "all or nothing".

`Sequelize` provides some methods for [many-to-many associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#-code-foo-belongstomany-bar----through--baz-----code-).  In this case, a separate call could be made for each junction table.

With this in mind, the following should accomplish the inserts without any duplicates:

```
let t = await sequelize.transaction()

try { 
    let order = await Order.create({
                userId: req.body.userId,
                sessionId: req.body.sessionId
            }, {
                transaction: t
            })

    let seats = await Seat.findAll({
            where: {
                id: {
                    [Op.in]: req.body.seatIds
                }
            }
        })
    let offsiteProducts = await OffsiteProducts.findAll({
            where: {
                id: {
                    [Op.in]: req.body.offsiteProductIds
                }
            }
        })
    
    await order.addSeats(seats, { transaction: t })
    await order.addOffsiteProducts(offsiteProducts, { transaction: t })

    await t.commit()
} catch (err) {
    if (t) {
        await t.rollback()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the primary keys for the rows in the `OffsiteProducts` and `Seats` tables are already known, the above could be shortened to:

```
let t = await sequelize.transaction()

try { 
    let order = await Order.create({
                userId: req.body.userId,
                sessionId: req.body.sessionId
            }, {
                transaction: t
            })

    await order.addSeats(req.body.seatIds, { transaction: t })
    await order.addOffsiteProducts(req.body.offsiteProductIds, { transaction: t })

    await t.commit()
} catch (err) {
    if (t) {
        await t.rollback()
    }
}
```

There's a bit more explanation for passing arrays of primary keys to the `.addSeats` and `.addOffsiteProducts` methods in the docs [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js%7EBelongsToMany.html).

Comment: That was just what I needed. Passing an array of ids instead of objects and making the operation asynchronous with the "add[Model]" methods did the job perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: One thing I'm struggling again with is how to insert extra data in the junction table.

The junction table "Reserved_offsite_products" expects a "quantity" that I have not managed to insert via array of numbers.

I have used the 'through' keyword as pointed in the documentation but it is not working:

`await order.addOffsiteProducts(req.body.offsiteProducts.ids, { through : { quantity : req.body.offsiteProducts.quantities }}, { transaction: t })`

Any help about this?

Comment: @AbelMoreno I think `.addOffsiteProducts` only takes two parameters.  Could you try `await order.addOffsiteProducts(req.body.offsiteProducts.ids, { through : { quantity : req.body.offsiteProducts.quantities }, transaction: t })`?

Comment: Once again, you got the solution. Tried everything but wrapping "through" and "transaction" together in the second parameter. I really appreciate your help. Have a look at my repository if you please. Any feedback is welcome https://github.com/doveriko/cinema-app

Comment: No worries @AbelMoreno, I wish you the best of luck!  Also, if you found the answer helpful, feel free to upvote it:)  Best of luck with your app!